# Java File Class ( constructor)

Tags: c#, java, .net, multithreading, file-io

```
File f = new File(filePath);

    RandomAccessFile rf=null;
    String firstLine="";
    if (f.isFile() && f.length() > 0) {
        rf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");

            rf.seek(0);
        firstLine = rf.readLine();
        rf.close();
```

Above code is used to read from a file in java constructor . Same file could be opened by different threads at the same time . Now i am making the code in C# and the File class like the one in java is not present . I want to ask what does the constructor of File class is doing here and how different is it from the method in which we simply use following.

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)
```

And why is random access file actually used when only line to be read from file is the first line.
as there are different threads it could be possible that when one thread is reading or writing in the file at the same time other thread would be reading the file as well . How can we allow it in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string firstLine = file.ReadLine();
file.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry i did not mention as there are different threads it could be possible that when one thread is reading or writing in the file at the same time other thread would be reading the file as well . How can we allow it in C#